# Draw a Shape within paint method

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

My program is a method to draw a circle on `JPanel` with multi-thread. The following is a part of my code. I can draw a `Image` in the paint method, but I can't draw a `Shape` in paint method.  What's wrong with it?

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    if (draw == true) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
            for (Star s : this.items) {
                g2d.draw(s.cirle);
            }
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();
    }
}

// a constructor of my star class
public Star(int delay,int initialX,int initialY){
    //ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("star.jpg"));
    //starImage = ii.getImage();
    Shape circle = new Ellipse2D.Float(initialX,initialY,100f,100f);
    System.out.println(circle);
    x=initialX;
    y=initialY;
    randomDesXY();
    this.delay=delay;
}
```

### Error message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.geom.Path2D$Float.<init>(Path2D.java:232)
    at java.awt.geom.Path2D$Float.<init>(Path2D.java:207)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.BufferedRenderPipe.draw(BufferedRenderPipe.java:525)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.PixelToParallelogramConverter.draw(PixelToParallelogramConverter.java:148)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.ValidatePipe.draw(ValidatePipe.java:154)
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.draw(SunGraphics2D.java:2383)
    at tma1.Board.paint(Board.java:61)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:770)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:728)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:677)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:59)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1621)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.geom.Path2D$Float.<init>(Path2D.java:232)
    at java.awt.geom.Path2D$Float.<init>(Path2D.java:207)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.BufferedRenderPipe.draw(BufferedRenderPipe.java:525)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.PixelToParallelogramConverter.draw(PixelToParallelogramConverter.java:148)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.ValidatePipe.draw(ValidatePipe.java:154)
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.draw(SunGraphics2D.java:2383)
    at tma1.Board.paint(Board.java:61)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:770)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:728)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:677)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:59)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1621)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.geom.Path2D$Float.<init>(Path2D.java:232)
    at java.awt.geom.Path2D$Float.<init>(Path2D.java:207)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.BufferedRenderPipe.draw(BufferedRenderPipe.java:525)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.PixelToParallelogramConverter.draw(PixelToParallelogramConverter.java:148)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.ValidatePipe.draw(ValidatePipe.java:154)
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.draw(SunGraphics2D.java:2383)
    at tma1.Board.paint(Board.java:61)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:770)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:728)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:677)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:59)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1621)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.geom.Path2D$Float.<init>(Path2D.java:232)
    at java.awt.geom.Path2D$Float.<init>(Path2D.java:207)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.BufferedRenderPipe.draw(BufferedRenderPipe.java:525)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.PixelToParallelogramConverter.draw(PixelToParallelogramConverter.java:148)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.ValidatePipe.draw(ValidatePipe.java:154)
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.draw(SunGraphics2D.java:2383)
    at tma1.Board.paint(Board.java:61)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:770)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:728)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:677)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:59)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1621)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.geom.Path2D$Float.<init>(Path2D.java:232)
    at java.awt.geom.Path2D$Float.<init>(Path2D.java:207)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.BufferedRenderPipe.draw(BufferedRenderPipe.java:525)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.PixelToParallelogramConverter.draw(PixelToParallelogramConverter.java:148)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.ValidatePipe.draw(ValidatePipe.java:154)
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.draw(SunGraphics2D.java:2383)
    at tma1.Board.paint(Board.java:61)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:770)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:728)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:677)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:59)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1621)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.

................
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `Shape` from this code.

```
public Star(int delay,int initialX,int initialY){
    Shape circle = new Ellipse2D.Float(initialX,initialY,100f,100f);
```

Edit:

If you declare `Shape circle` in the constructor, then the word `circle` in the constructor means a *local variable* named `circle` (not an *attribute* `circle`). If you use NetBeans or Eclipse, you can check whether a variable is a local variable or an attribute by its color. The IDE highlights the color of attributes and local variables differently.

Comment: You are probably correct, 1+, but you'll want to tell him why this is so, including all about variable shadowing and how to prevent doing this.

Comment: if remove, the netbeans warn me: can't find symbol

Comment: Rename the attribute `cirle` to `circle`

Answer (score 3):

1. Custom painting should be done in the `paintComponent()` method, not the `paint()` method.
2. Don't use the `dispose()` method on the `Graphics` object. The only time you use `dispose()` is when you create your own `Graphics` object.
3. I have no idea why you are using the `sync()` method. I've never seen that in painting code before.